# Animate constraints, how to grow height in desired direction

Tags: swift, constraints, snapkit

Im using SnapKit to alter the height of a UIView based on a touch event. So when the user touches the cell it expands. This works fine like this:

```
@objc func didRecieveTouch() {
    let originalHeight: CGFloat = 90
    let expandedHeight: CGFloat = 244

    if !expanded {
        self.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(expandedHeight)
        }
    } else {
        self.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(originalHeight)
        }

    }
    self.expanded = !self.expanded
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

The problem is that the direction the view grows in looks weird and wrong to me. The view actually "hops" down to the new allocated space and grows upwards instead of growing downwards which is the desired behaviour I want.

[image]

Comment: can you please add from which part of code you are calling didRecieveTouch.and add some info about tableview setup.

Answer (score -2):

Add your code inside the animation block.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
    if !expanded {
        self.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(expandedHeight)
        }
    } else {
        self.snp.updateConstraints { make in
            make.height.equalTo(originalHeight)
       }
    }
    self.expanded = !self.expanded
    self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Comment: No. I have no idea what the snap kit is but normally, you update your constraints and layout in an animation block. Since they made a library to set constraints, my best guess is you don't even need to layout manually. They should have done that in the library.

Comment: @desdenova Why would you answer on SnapKit issue if you're not sure how it works? https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/199